# How to generate random integer pairs between 0 and 31?

Tags: python, numpy, random, integer

As the title illustrated, I want to generate 100 pairs of random integers, such as `(1, 0)`, `(1, 31)`, `(5, 7)`, `(3, 19)` and so on. And the range of value is from 0 to 31. At the same time, I hope each pair appears only once within the 100 pairs, i.e., the value of each pair is different from others.

So How can I achieve it in Python?

**Supplement:**

To be precise, what I  want is a 2D array, and its shape is (100,2). Each row is required to be unique.

Comment: note that you should expect to start seeing duplicates at around 32 pairs.  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: Do the pairs for example ( 3, 2 ) and ( 2, 3 ) count as different pairs?

Comment: @TlsChris Yes, they are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

pool_ = [ (i,j) for i in range(32) for j in range(32) ]
# List of all pairs

pool = np.zeros( len(pool_), dtype = tuple ) # Create an np.array of tuples

pool[:] = pool_  # fill it with pool_

selected = np.random.choice( pool, replace = False, size =100 )
# select 100 random choices from the pool, without replacement

print( selected )
# [(0, 22) (4, 30) (2, 25) (4, 19) (6, 6) (17, 22) (18, 14) (12, 27) (30, 6)
# (22, 18) (13, 5) (23, 22) (27, 17) (17, 26) (26, 22) (7, 15) (15, 27)
# (4, 31) (15, 1) (28, 22) (25, 16) (25, 15) (7, 12) (7, 21) (26, 14)
# (9, 9) (8, 0) (26, 27) (14, 14) (22, 0) (4, 18) (12, 3) (25, 9) (22, 31)
# (11, 6) (23, 7) (18, 19) (19, 25) (23, 19) (25, 5) (5, 19) (3, 24)
# (30, 0) (18, 10) (20, 4) (24, 11) (13, 28) (10, 5) (6, 7) (11, 7)
# (25, 24) (23, 18) (15, 10) (14, 7) (11, 11) (9, 23) (13, 8) (3, 28)
# (28, 3) (21, 3) (24, 31) (29, 27) (24, 28) (17, 6) (30, 19) (25, 28)
# (12, 17) (13, 15) (3, 11) (14, 1) (12, 6) (17, 17) (23, 2) (24, 18)
# (25, 11) (3, 26) (6, 2) (0, 28) (5, 12) (4, 1) (23, 17) (29, 23) (22, 17)
# (24, 15) (2, 5) (28, 11) (19, 27) (9, 20) (1, 11) (30, 5) (30, 21)
# (30, 28) (18, 31) (5, 27) (30, 11) (16, 0) (24, 16) (12, 30) (25, 25)
# (16, 22)]
```

I haven't thoroughly tested it but with `replace = False` in random.choice each selection should be unique.

**To return a 2D array**

```
import numpy as np

pool_ = [ (i,j) for i in range(32) for j in range(32) ]
# List of all pairs

pool_ix = np.arange( len(pool_) ) # index by row

pool = np.array(pool_) # 2D pool

selected_ix = np.random.choice( pool_ix, replace = False, size =100 )

pool[selected_ix, : ]  # Select all of each selected row.

# array([[12, 19],
#        [ 6, 23],
#        [ 2,  3],
#        [ 5, 20],
#           :::
#        [20,  3],
#        [24, 20],
#        [ 1, 28]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
import random

pool = range(32)
random.sample(pool, 2)
# [7, 28]
random.sample(pool, 2)
# [15, 3]
```

Comment: So with ```random.sample```, I need to iterate 32 times